# Argue that $1/\sin(x)\to \infty$ as $x\to 0^+$ mathematically

Tags: real-analysis, limits

How to explain mathematically that $\sin(x)^{-1}\to \infty$ as $x\to 0^+$ without looking at the graph? What I think in two situations:

(1) Since $\sin(x)\to 0$ as $x\to 0^+$, for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $\vert\sin(x)\vert<\epsilon$ for all $x\in (0,\delta)$. Letting $N>0$ be given and replace $\epsilon$ by $1/N$, you get $\vert\sin(x)\vert<1/N$ for all $x\in (0,\delta)$. What I want is to go from here to this: $\sin(x)^{-1}>N$ for all $x\in (0,\delta)$. Am I allowed to make $\delta$ small enough that $\sin(x)$ is positive?

Or ...

(2) This follows from the fact that $\sin(x)$ is positive in $(0,\pi/2)$ and is decreasing for $x\to 0^+$. What I want to show is, how it is decreasing when $x\to 0^+$. Is it because that $\sin$ is increasing in $(0,\pi/2)$, then we can go backward from $x=\pi/2$ to near $x=0$ to say that it is decreasing?

Comment: I think you have the right idea, but you've got $\sin(x)<1/N$ and then you want $\frac{1}{\sin(x)} > N.$ Since $N$ can be made arbitrarily large, then you have the desired result.

Comment: @Chickenmancer How do you go from $\vert\sin(x)\vert<1/N$ to $\sin(x)<1/N$ if you do not know how small $\delta$ is? This is what I am asking in first option.

Comment: I would use $|\sin x|\le |x|$ explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take your value of $\delta$ and replace it by the smaller of $\delta$ and $\pi$. That will guarantee that $\sin x$ is positive when you need it to be.

The fact that $\sin x$ is increasing on the interval $(0, \pi/2)$ is irrelevant.

Comment: Okay, so I can say something like: For every $N>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $\vert \sin(x)\vert < 1/N$ for all $x\in (0,\delta)$. In particular $ \sin(x) < 1/N$ for all $x\in (0,\delta^*)$, where $\delta^*<\min\{\delta,\pi\}$. So, now since $1/\sin(x)>N$ for all $x\in (0,\delta^*)$, the desired result is obtained?

Comment: Sure. That kind of argument is quite common. You'll often see the choice of $\delta$ as that kind of minimum right from the start.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll keep it in mind. You mentioned that the information on $\sin$ increasing in $(0,\pi/2)$ is irrelevant. The reason I asked is that it would imply that $1/\sin$ is decreasing in the interval, and hence (intuitively) going from near $x=\pi/2$ to near $x=0$, it would be increasing and goes to infinity. Is this still wrong?

Comment: That's right, but not relevant or needed. All you care about is the inequality.